# Which StartingPosition Type to use when a Kinesis Consumer restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, position, amazon-kinesis, consumer

I have read the [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_StartingPosition.html) about StartingPosition for kinesis consumer. Still not sure whether TRIM_HORIZON or LASTEST to be used under the condition that the consumer is down for 10 hours and comes up again.

LASTEST is reading the most recent records in the shard, i believe it reads the records in real time and the ones in the future, so it will skip records that are 10hrs old.

TRIM_HORIZON is reading the oldest data in the shard, for this one, i'm not sure whether it reprocesses the data older than 10hrs, or it skips processed records and start processing those records are between 10hrs old and latest? Not sure what does the "oldest" exactly mean. Does it mean the oldest and unprocessed?

My question is which type to use to pick up those 10hrs old records? Please help explain. Thanks in advance.

I used [harlow/kinesis-consumer](https://github.com/harlow/kinesis-consumer) package to read, this package is using LATEST by default. So not sure if TRIM_HORIZON is the right type to use.

Comment: `TRIM_HORIZON`, but this will read everything from the beginning. Normally you should keep sharditernator yourself, e.g. in dynamodb, so that you can restart at the correct position.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, Marcin. And the package itself explains the case in README "To record the progress of the consumer in the stream (checkpoint) we use a storage layer to persist the last sequence number the consumer has read from a particular shard. The boolean value ErrSkipCheckpoint of consumer.ScanError determines if checkpoint will be activated. ScanError is returned by the record processing callback. This will allow consumers to re-launch and pick up at the position in the stream where they left off."